# select2 обновление data

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Подскажите как обновить в select2 выбранные поля

```
var input = $('#placeSelect')
var btn = $('button')

input.select2({
    width: '100%',
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: true,
    maximumSelectionSize: 1,
    placeholder: "Click here and start typing to search.",
    data: [
            { id: 1, text: "Ford"     },
            { id: 2, text: "Dodge"    },
            { id: 3, text: "Mercedes" },
            { id: 4, text: "Jaguar"   }
          ]    
});

input.change(function(){
   console.log($(this).select2('data')) // выводит выбранные поля 
})

btn.click(function(){

    var data = select.select2('data');
    var newData = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i].id == closeBtnId) {
           continue;
        }

        newData.push(data[i]);
    }

    input.select2('data', newData); // нужно обновить выбранные поля в соответствии с преданными данными
})
```

Comment: пробуй занести в переменную новые данные и в btn функцию закинуть эту переменную

Comment: ну понятно что newData это новые данные - просто расписывать не стал

Comment: так, а где идет запись в ньюдата?

Comment: var data = select.select2('data');
    var newData = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i].id == closeBtnId) {
            continue;
        }
        newData.push(data[i]);
    }

Comment: лучше в инпут всю функцию занеси и потом отображай при клике, ты перебираешь всю дату вновь и толку нету

Comment: @ruslik версия какая у вас select2?

Answer (score 1):

$(".js-example-data-array-selected").select2({
  data: data
}) взято с [сайта](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data)

Comment: в вашем варианте идет обновление всего data, а не выбранных элементов